# How to capture displayed html in a variable

Tags: html, ios, variables, uinavigationbar, title

## The App

I have an iOS app that consist of a menu (table). From the menu the user is sent to a relevant local html files displayed in two webViews. I am interested in setting the title of the navigation bar to the name of the html file.

## So far

It works using

```
- (void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender: (id) sender
{    
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showWeb"]) {

//       NSString *myLabel = rowText ;
       ViewController *detailsTVC = [segue destinationViewController];
       detailsTVC.label = rowText; //rowText;
    }

    if ( [segue isKindOfClass: [SWRevealViewControllerSegue class]] ) {
        SWRevealViewControllerSegue *swSegue = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue*) segue;

        swSegue.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvc_segue,     UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc) {

            UINavigationController* navController =     (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
            [navController setViewControllers: @[dvc] animated: NO ];
            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
        };

    }

}
```

This works perfectly when the user tabs an item in the menu.

## The Problem

However, the problem is that I have links in the html files, which links to other local html files, and when the user press the links, of course, the title does not change.

**The basic question is, how do I capture/store a variable, which contains information on which html is displayed?**
It must not be through the table because it will not capture redirection through links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to become a `UIWebView`'s delegate in your viewcontroller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _webview.delegate = self;
}
```

and implement `-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` delegate's method, then you can get current document title by evaluating javascript `document.title`

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString *documentTitle = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
    [self setTitle:documentTitle];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this would help

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     if(indexPath.row == 0)
          self.navigationController.navigationItem.title = @"Your 0th html title";
     if(indexPath.row == 1)
          self.navigationController.navigationItem.title = @"Your 1st html title";
     [self viewDidLoad];
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not solve the problem, since it only works for navigation through my menu. I need a sort of universal method, that also works when tapping on a link in the html file.

Comment: can you please add code of your segue on didSelectRowAtIndexPath. I could not trace the actual problem.

Comment: It tried to make the question easier to understand - it is a bit difficult to explain :)